# Как сделать автоматическое построение графиков по каждому из столбцов датафрейма?

Tags: python, pandas, циклы

Есть датафрейм следующего вида
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

НАчинаю с ним работу:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_excel('BP.xlsx', sheet_name='Лист2')
```

Мне нужно, чтобы запускался цикл и шел по каждому столбцу и строил по каждому отдельную гистограмму и сохранял эти картинки.
Никак не могу реализовать...
Помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: А в чём проблема? Список столбцов - `df.columns`, перебирайте его в цикле и берите данные через `df[<название_столбца>]`

Comment: Дело в том, что я новичок и, похоже, получилась какая-то дичь    

'''import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_excel('BP.xlsx', sheet_name='Лист2')
peremennaya = []
for col in df.columns:
        fig = sns.distplot(peremennaya)
        plt.savefig("{}.png".format(str(col)))
        fig.show()'''

Comment: `sns.distplot(df[col])`

Comment: Всё получилось!!! Спасибо Вам, дорогой человек! Очень благодарю!

Comment: @lo Io -  а почему бы вам не поблагодарить того, кто вам помог так, как это принято на этом сайте?

Comment: и как же это сделать? Не совсем очевидно